# Using FORALL statement to Insert data from jdbc prepared statement

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql

I'm trying to improve the performance of insertion a bulk operation which can takes up to 10 minutes in an oracle 11g2 database with jdbc batch insert (addBatch() + executeBatch()) .

I have tried to use the APPEND_VALUES hint with jdbc batch, but it result with an exception:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12838: cannot read/modify an object after modifying it in parallel
```

So I'm trying to use the FORALL statement with PSQL in such a way:

```
DECLARE
   type TObjectTable is table of ALL_OBJECTS%ROWTYPE;
   ObjectTable$ TObjectTable;
   l_data ARRAY;
   CURSOR c IS WITH ALL_OBJECTS as (
        SELECT 1    'firstname1',   'secondname' FROM DUAL UNION ALL,
        SELECT 2    'firstname2',   'secondname2' FROM DUAL
         ) SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS;
BEGIN
   OPEN c;
   LOOP
   FETCH c BULK COLLECT INTO ld_data LIMIT 2;
   FORALL i in 1..l_data.COUNT
   INSERT INTO t1 VALUES l_data(i);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c;
END;
```

Where the values in the WITH clause would be bind parameters in the javacode.
I still can't make this work without the jdbc part and I'm wondering if there would be a better way of doing so. This feels very hacky, but the improvement are essential.

Comment: you sure that works? FORALL doesn't have an END LOOP statement...

Comment: No I can't make it work ... I tried adding a END LOOP but still not working, I have this error comming up any way

    ORA-06550: line 6, column 14:
PL/SQL: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

But I'm not sure I'm going through the right method to speed up the insert ... wondering if the FORALL is not meant to be used with already existing data.

Comment: remove the "," after union all. And again: forall doesn't have end loop